How to select a new option from country borders dropdown menu and have it return data for only that option
I have populated a dropdown menu of countries from a local country borders json file using php and Ajax. Everything is populated fine and when a new country is selected the leaflet.js map zooms to the correct country highlighting the border. However when, a new option(country) is selected it will go to this country and highlight but, the previous option is still highlighted on the map too. I wanted some direction on how to only have the current option highlighted not any previously selected countries. I feel there is something obvious i am missing...
This is what I have so far:
$("#countrySelect").on('change',function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "php/borders.php",
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
    
       name: 'name',
       iso_a2: $('#countrySelect').val()
    
    },
      success: function(data) {
      $('#countrySelect option:selected').val();
  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.data));
        border = L.geoJSON(data.data,{
          style:{
            weight: 1,
            fillColor: 'green',
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'green',
            fillOpacity: 0.2
          }
      });
        border.addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(border.getBounds());
         
  },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
}})
});


This solved the problem, had to empty 'border' first Used the following code:                                      if(border != ''){
border.clearLayers();
}   /Used this before declaring border/ Hope it helps someone!
